# Communicate with a Skype bot in preview-mode?

Tags: ms-office, bots, skype, skype-bots

I've written a Skype bot using the new [Skype Bot SDK](https://www.skype.com/en/developer/) . I've uploaded my WebAPI-based bot on Azure and added the bot application in the Skype bot dashboard. However, there is no information on how to add the bot to my local Skype account in order to communicate with the bot. I've read that I can publish the bot and afterwards add it to the global Skype directory, however, this should be done only after the bot has been thoroughly tested. So how to test it beforehand?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution: go to ["My bots"](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/skype/bots/manage) -> click on the name of your bot -> click the "Add bot to Skype" link.